Differences in meaning for notations $\alpha_i$ versus $\alpha(i)$ for exponents in monomials ordering
The following are partly taken from Malik and Sen's Fundamentals of Abstract Algebra
Background

First we note that we can reconstruct the monomial $x^\alpha=x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$ from $n$-tuple of exponents $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots\alpha_n)\in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$. $\vdots$
Lemma 1: An order relation $>$ on $\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$ is a well-ordering if and only if every strictly decreasing sequence in $\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$
$$\alpha(1)>\alpha(2)>\alpha(3)>\cdots$$
eventually terminates.

Lemma 2:  Let $I$ be a momomial ideal and $f\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n]$.
Then the following are equivalent
$(i)$ $f\in I$.
$(ii)$ Every term of $f$ lies in $I$.
$(iii)$ $f=\sum_{\alpha=0}^{t} a_\alpha x^{\alpha}$ for some $a_\alpha \in K$ and $x^\alpha\in I, 0\leq \alpha \leq t$.

Proof: That $(iii)\Rightarrow (ii)\Rightarrow(i)$ is immediate.
$(i)\Rightarrow (iii)$    Since $f\in I, f=\sum_{i=1}^{q} h_{i} x^{\alpha(i)}$ for some $h_i\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $\alpha(i)\in A$, where $I=\langle\{x^\alpha\mid\alpha \in A\}\rangle$.  Now $h_i=\sum_{j=0}^{n_i} k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)}, i=1,\ldots,q, k_{ij}\in K,$ for all $i,j$. Thus,
$$f=\sum_{i=1}^{q}\sum_{j=q}^{m_i} k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)}x^{\alpha(i)}$$
Therefore, $(iii)$ holds since $x^{\beta(ij)}x^{\alpha(i)}$ is a monomial in $I$.

Here is a screenshot of Lemma 2 (Lemma 27.2.14 in the screenshot),

Questions
I have some questions about notations for denoting exponents for monomials.
Suppose as in the indented exposition above Lemma 1 where if we have $x^\alpha=x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$ where $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots\alpha_n)\in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$, then in the case of Lemma 1, we have notations like $\alpha(1)>\alpha(2)>\alpha(3)>\cdot$, I mean does $\alpha(i)$ and $\alpha_i$ mean the same thing?
Also in the case of Lemma 2, how does $j$ relate to $i$?
I looked at few other texts on the beginning of Groebner bases on the section about monomial ordering.
All of these texts I have consulted never state the precise differences between the use of the two notations.
Thank you in advance

Here , $\alpha$ is $n$-tuple , while $\alpha_i$ is some element of that $n$-tuple.
That notation is using $\alpha(i)$ to indicate some whole $n$-tuple , not element of $n$-tuple.
Example :
Let us say we have the monomial like $x^2yz^3$ , then we make the $3$-tuple triplet $\alpha=(2,1,3)$
Here $\alpha_1=2$ , $\alpha_2=1$ , $\alpha_3=3$
Now we can make a list of monomials like $x^2y^2z^2$ , $y^2z^3$ , $x^2z^3$ , $x^2y$
Then we will have $\alpha(1)=(2,2,2)$ , $\alpha(2)=(0,2,3)$ , $\alpha(3)=(2,0,3)$ , $\alpha(4)=(2,1,0)$
The Lemma 1 claims that every strictly decreasing sequence with well-ordering will always terminate.

Can I ask what about the notation $\beta(ij)$ in Lemma 2? Does $j$ depend on $i$?  if not, how are the two indices related?

((1)) I am not able to make much sense there because there are some mix-ups with $a$ & $\alpha$ while $A$ is undefined, Can you copy-paste the actual snippet ? ((2)) The $i$ & $j$ are not related & we have to consider all such pairs. Dependency is there between $\beta$ & $\alpha$ to make sure that $x^\beta x^\alpha$ is in $I$ & in $f$

I have added a screenshot of the Lemma and proof. I reread it again and I try to apply what you said about $ \alpha()$, to $\beta()$ but I still can't manage to make heads or tails of it.  Also can I also trouble you with the following post. It is about counting bases elements for the dimension of $\text{dim}_k k[x_1,…,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$...

...but is in the form of a two sided inequaliy. I think i managed to do one side of the inequality, but not the other. Thank you in advance.
